# python - How do i remove duplicates but keep row values in other column

Tags: python

i have a small df with: ID and full Name
and i want to remove duplicates in ID but keep all names in new columns (kind of explode)
so if i have 3 same ids, i would have new df with columns: ID, name, name, name

Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a programming question than a data science question and would therefore be better suited to the stackoverflow stackexchange page. Given the following dataframe with an `ID` and `name` column

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4],
    "name": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
})

df.head()
```

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | D |
| 2 | E |

this can be achieved by using a combination of [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
df = (
    df
    .groupby("ID")
    .agg({"name": lambda x: list(x)})
    .reset_index()
)
pd.concat([df["ID"], pd.DataFrame(df["name"].values.tolist()).add_prefix("name_")], axis=1)
```

This returns the following dataframe:

| ID | name_0 | name_1 | name_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C |
| 2 | D | E |  |
| 3 | F | G | H |
| 4 | I | J |  |